# Electron NSIS prevent reinstalling

Tags: electron, windows-installer, nsis

Is there a way to have the NSIS built by Electron not re-install the app everytime it is clicked just like the MSI ? If the app is already installed I would like it to simply open it rather than re-installing.

I would use the MSI but when I open the app installed by it, it doesn't have read/write permissions from files inside the directory even if it is in Appdata (same folder as installation from NSIS). When installed from NSIS for some reason it gives read/write permissions to the app for files inside the installation directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If this was pure NSIS I would just tell you to add something to .onInit but I have no clue about electron and I try to avoid it at all costs, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your .nsi script file and do the check manually (skip the installation if an app is already installed) because there is no "switch" for that.

The issue with electron NSIS installers is that script is recreated every time (at least in the tutorials I saw) so you may lose any changes you made there.

In such case you cannot use the building pipeline, but you need to open the .nsi file with text editor, make the changes and compile everything with makensis.

Please post your script with more details.